# Python Hangman game - how to replace multiple instances of the same value in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stumped trying to figure this out. I'm building a pretty typical hangman game in Python 3, and it's all going swimmingly except when the player enters a letter in the randomly generated word, only the first instance of that letter in the word is revealed. Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? Here is my function:

```
def reveal_letter(player_guess, mystery_word, word_update, blank_list):
mys_list = list(mystery_word)
    for item in mys_list:
        if str(player_guess) == item:
            blank_list[mys_list.index(str(player_guess))] = str(player_guess)
    return blank_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.index()` which always returns the first match it finds.  You can use `enumerate()` here:

```
def reveal_letter(player_guess, mystery_word, word_update, blank_list):
    for index, item in enumerate(mystery_word):
        if player_guess == item:
            blank_list[i] = player_guess

    return blank_list
```

Note that `[][0] = None` raises an `IndexError`.  If `blank_list` really is a blank list, you should use `blank_list.append(player_guess)` instead of the assignment and add `else: blank_list.append("_")` after it.  If it is not a blank list, I would suggest giving it a more descriptive name.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance zondo, However, I am still only returning the string with the first letter revealed. I added a variable that creates a string out of blank_list (which after it runs through the loops should include underscores as well as the guessed letter) which the function returns. The resulting string is thus mostly blank underscores with the guessed character included. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? The for loop should read over every letter in the list and where it encounters the matching letter in the list, replace that indexed letter with the player_guess letter, correct?

Comment: Is `blank_list` really a blank list?  If it is, you need to add the underscores yourself.  If it isn't, my answer should work.  I have explained how above.  If you are still having problems, could you post your code in a pastebin along with the traceback?

Comment: Haha, sorry man I'm so green I don't know what traceback is. Here's a link to the pastebin, I hope this is what you meant. I've commented out my original code for the function that is giving me problems, I've tried to comment in the rationale for the rest of my admittedly inelegant code:

http://pastebin.com/fmpuwxNg

oh and the blank_list is not an empty list, it's a list of underscores which I concatenate into a string. My idea was replace the index in the list w/ the corresponding index in a list made of the letters in the mystery word, then return the list of underscores w/ added letter.

Comment: The traceback is the error that is displayed.  It starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ends with an error message.  You had a couple problems.  The updated code is [here](http://pastebin.com/BggtaYmn).  Your other levels aren't working, but at least the hard level is working.  I think the others aren't working because you didn't define a word for them.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @G.Threepwood: It's a pleasure.  If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the greyed-out check mark below the vote count.